# Duplicate questions for merging/deleting

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I have been working on completing a thorough examination of the query from [Duplicate Titles needing improvement and/or closed as duplicate](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3347/duplicate-titles-needing-improvement-and-or-closed-as-duplicate), and found many posts were duplicates from single users, that now require merging. Some may need deleting though, if they just have bad answers.

- Can FireFox be Installed with a Fixed Set of Extensions that cannot
     be Changed by End-Users? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/142745/can-firefox-be-installed-with-a-fixed-set-of-extensions-that-cannot-be-changed-by) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/143010/can-firefox-be-installed-with-a-fixed-set-of-extensions-that-cannot-be-changed-by)
- my ubuntu laptop is not detecting my headphone - [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/172773/my-ubuntu-laptop-is-not-detecting-my-headphone) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/172777/my-ubuntu-laptop-is-not-detecting-my-headphone)
- Windows 7 Built-In VPN - How to access network shares, printers, etc.? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/230961/windows-7-built-in-vpn-how-to-access-network-shares-printers-etc) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/232199/windows-7-built-in-vpn-how-to-access-network-shares-printers-etc)
- Shoud I use ffmpeg to have videoCodecId = 2 or 7? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/289192/shoud-i-use-ffmpeg-to-have-videocodecid-2-or-7) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/289656/shoud-i-use-ffmpeg-to-have-videocodecid-2-or-7)
- How can I set Excel to always import all columns of CSV files as Text? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/306315/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text)
- Why won't USB Plug & Play work? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/29538/why-wont-usb-plug-play-work) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/29636/why-wont-usb-plug-play-work)
- Internet very slow when upgrading to Ubuntu 9.10 - [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/67599/internet-very-slow-when-upgrading-to-ubuntu-9-10) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/67686/internet-very-slow-when-upgrading-to-ubuntu-9-10)
- How to record screencast on Linux with mouse clicks and key hits shown - [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/108619/how-to-record-screencast-on-linux-with-mouse-clicks-and-key-hits-shown) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/116320/how-to-record-screencast-on-linux-with-mouse-clicks-and-key-hits-shown)
- How can I take browser screenshots at a higher resolution than my browser supports? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/120266/how-can-i-take-browser-screenshots-at-a-higher-resolution-than-my-browser-support) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/203490/how-can-i-take-browser-screenshots-at-a-higher-resolution-than-my-browser-support)
- How do I change permissions for Windows\Temp? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/194586/how-do-i-change-permissions-for-windows-temp) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/194845/how-do-i-change-permissions-for-windows-temp)
- microsoft outlook question - wiped out email in actual server? [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/199658/microsoft-outlook-question-wiped-out-email-in-actual-server) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/199897/microsoft-outlook-question-wiped-out-email-in-actual-server)
- SuperSlow raid1/raid6 with dual core Intel Atom - [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/218935/superslow-raid1-raid6-with-dual-core-intel-atom) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/258070/superslow-raid1-raid6-with-dual-core-intel-atom)
- Where are product uninstall keys located in the Registry under
  Windows 7 x64? - [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/220637/where-are-product-uninstall-keys-located-in-the-registry-under-windows-7-x64) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/221072/where-are-product-uninstall-keys-located-in-the-registry-under-windows-7-x64)
- Why do my virtual machines slow down/freeze under Hyper-V Server 2008 - [Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/220638/why-do-my-virtual-machines-slow-down-freeze-under-hyper-v-server-2008) [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/220645/why-do-my-virtual-machines-slow-down-freeze-under-hyper-v-server-2008)

Thanks to the moderators who dealt with all my flags today!

Comment: Thanks for taking the initiative to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed / Merged / deleted / left alone as applicable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the effort to help go through these

Comment: you're welcome @SimonSheehan. Thanks for taking the time to find and post these.

Comment: and a huge thank to @PaŭloEbermann for starting the hunt for this.